# Converter base64 para pdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Eu tenho em minha aplicação uma função que converte o pdf em base64 e salva no banco e então, preciso retornar essa base64 e mostrar o conteudo do arquivo original.

```
    $('#form-job').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('aqui');
    var inputs = $(e.target).find('[name]').serializeArray();

    var reader = new FileReader(),
        file = $('#resume')[0];

    if (!file.files.length) {
        alert('no file uploaded');
        return false;
    }

    var url = "http://localhost:5000/api/curriculum";
    reader.onload = function () {
        var data = reader.result,
            base64 = data.replace(/^[^,]*,/, '');

        inputs.push({name:'resume', value: base64});                        

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: inputs,
            success: function (response) {
                $(".contato-quad-formulario-right-enviar").hide()
                $(".contato-quad-formulario-right-enviar-sucesso").show()
                $(".contato-quad-formulario-right, .contato-quad-formulario-left").fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
             }
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);                
});
```

É uma questão da empresa fazer desse jeito, salvar em base64 e depois mostrar o conteúdo original. Agora que vem meu problema, não consigo de forma alguma mostrar o conteúdo original. Como posso fazer para criar um pdf a partir da base64 que é retornado para mim. Se ajudar posso retornar o valor salvo no banco como buffer ou em base64 qual é melhor ?

Comment: Seria mais viável uma solução com o header (cabeçalho), você está usando PHP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080341/correct-php-headers-for-pdf-file-download

Comment: Estou usando JavaScript com bundle para salvar e angularjs para mostrar o pdf